# Haskell Function Building for Lists

Tags: haskell

I am trying to build a function that reacts differently depending on whether the parameter is an empty list or a list containing something. My code:

```
validateCypher :: [Char] -> [Char]
validateCypher [] = cypherB
validateCyper n:[] = ['O']
```

Which however returns

Syntax error in declaration (unexpected symbol ":")

Ideas? :)

Comment: You probably want `validateCypher` on the third line

Answer (score 8):

You need to put `(`..`)` around `n:[]`. But note that `(n:[])` is the same as `[n]`.

Comment: Yes, that is what I want

Comment: Ok, just checking :-)